# How to de-bloat Word 2007 .docx file

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I've got a 84 page document that is over 13M in size!  Another related document is much less than 1M, and it has a similar number of pages, pictures and tables.  Is there a way to compact or clean up .docx files?  It just doesn't make sense that it is that huge!

It was initially created as a .doc file, and that old copy is huge too.

Comment: have you tried "save as" to resave as a new docx? you can also try do extract the file with 7zip or winrar (yes it's simply a zipped file with xml's inside) to see what's the main reason of the big filesize.

Comment: Put something about making a copy ending with .zip and looking at it that way to see the bloat, and I'll accept your answer.  The pictures are .png, and every one is huge.  If I change the graphic type, I think I can get it to a more reasonable size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the PNG's to JPG's firstly. Secondly, try the following:

1. Select All > Copy
2. Create new Word Doc & Paste
3. Save and Close

This MIGHT reduce the file size by eliminating a large history of changes etc.

Comment: For the firstly.  The secondly didn't help, but after the firstly, it also wasn't needed.